# Calling no-argument constructor in superclass implicitly

Tags: java

This is taken from : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the
>
> Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument
>   constructor of
>
> the superclass.**If the super class does not have a no-argument
>   constructor,**
>
> you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a
>   constructor, so
>
> if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

I made this small example to test that :

class P as superclass (its empty class):

```
package org.standro.com.pk1;


public class P {
}
```

and class N in different package , class N extends class P without explicilty calling super() :

```
import org.standro.com.pk1.P;


public class N extends P {

    public N() {
        //imlicitly super() is called here .. that means the constructor of P 

    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
    N n=new N();

    }
}
```

and no compile error.. Im using JDK1.7
whats wrong with this example and why I don't get error ?

I think the bold sentence above should be :

**If the super class does not have a any constructor,....**

because if there is at least one constructor .. compiler will get error..

or please if anyone has explanation ..

thanks

Comment: _"You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler **automatically provides a no-argument**, default constructor for **any class without constructors**."_ Since you didn't specify a constructor for your class `P`, the compiler added the no-args one for you, thus the implicit `super();` call in your `N` class is valid.

Comment: Saying compiler will add no-arg constructor means that constructor doesn't exists there ..so based on the bold sentence above , why there is no compiler-time error   ?

Comment: I don't get you. The `P` class has a no-args constructor. If look at the bytecode generated by your P class, you will see it.

Comment: thats what I was looking for .. and because of that I wonder why not to clarify the sentence and rewrite to : If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor AND have (at least) an argument constructor ....then compiler will complain .. am I right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the class P extends object, and has no constructor, it's constructor defaults to the no argument constructor which implicitly invokes the constructor in Object.

To cause an error, you need to add a parameter to P's constructor like this:

```
public class P {

    public P(int a) {
    }
}
```

Now N tried to implicitly call super() which looks for a no-args constructor in P. However, since we added a constructor in P, the default no-args constructor can no longer be used.

Claification:

If there is no constructor, default no-arg one is added. If there is a constructor of any kind, the default no-arg constructor is not added

Comment: I understand that .. but still the sentence :If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor is ambiguous, I can understand it as the superclass has no-arg constructor but it has another arg-contractor and in this case I can make that error but also it can be understood that there is no constructor at all and so the no-arg constructor will added by compiler and no error .. am I right ?

Comment: Yup. If there is no constructor, default no-arg one is added. If there is a constructor of any kind, the default no-arg constructor is not added.

Answer (score 1):

As per your explanation only, if subclass is not calling super class constructor
then automatically compiler inserts an internal call to super class's no arg constrcutor.

so in class N ,you have `N()` constructor and its internally calling P class no arg constructor.

and P internally calls Object class no arg constructor.

so your code will compile successfully.

if there is no corresponding constructor in super class then only it complains.

so try to put some parameterized constrcutor in base class `P(like p(int x){  })` and run your program.
you will surely get error because of no arg costrcutor is not available in super class.

Note : no arg constrcutor is inserted only if there is no constrcutor at all in the class.